# Recurring memberships - authorize.net

Tags: civimember, authorize.net

We have memberships set up on our site, which are required to auto-renew. The page is set up to allow payments via credit card (Authorize.net), Paypal, and offline. Paypal works fine for recurring transactions. Authorize.net, however, appears to only be working for recurring contributions. Those show up in the transaction report over at Authorize.net just fine - even shows how many contributions the person signed up for, how many are remaining, etc. But not a single one of the memberships paid for via credit card show up over there as recurring.

Is there something I am missing?

Update:

Just had a transaction come through on the membership page. As I said earlier, all transactions are set to require auto-renew. The transaction details over at Authorize.net said:

Recurring Billing Transaction:  N

So obviously something isn't being sent to Authorize.net properly on the membership pages, but is working fine for contributions.

Comment: Just checking back in - has anyone run into this issue?

Comment: Checking in again. We're still having this issue, so we're having to run memberships as just contributions instead so that it does the recurring transactions.

Comment: I am also running into this issue.